# use 'start' and 'end' values in two columns to specify fill range over remaining columns in R

Tags: r, data.table, conditional-statements, fill

I need to fill each row of a matrix with '1' between 'start' and 'end' columns, where the 'start' and 'end' column names (dates in the real data) are specified for each 'id' in two columns of the matrix.

e.g.

```r
library(data.table)

d<- data.table(id = c("id_1","id_2"), 
               start.date = c(as.Date("2021-06-01"), as.Date("2021-07-02")), 
               end.date = c(as.Date("2021-08-04"), as.Date("2021-09-12")))

> d
     id start.date   end.date
1: id_1 2021-06-01 2021-08-04
2: id_2 2021-07-02 2021-09-12
```

The goal is to get a count of the number of individuals that fall on each date.  With a smaller dataset I would do this:

```
expand.dates<- function(start.date, end.date){
  dates<- seq.Date(start.date, end.date, "1 day")
}



##join expanded dates list to the original data.table 'd' on 'id'
xx<- d[d[,.(dates = expand.dates(start.date, end.date)), by = id], on = .(id)]

cnts<- xx[,.(counts = .N), by = .(dates)]
```

But the real data has several million individual IDs and the above approach leads to a memory error (cannot create vector of 8.5GB), so I am trying to 'cast' the date ranges and then run colSums across the dates to get the counts.

Comment: It may actually be easier to work with number-like columns like `Date`s instead of letters, since the former supports `seq`.

Comment: Are you looking to *create* the columns `c:f` based on the values in `a:b` (here), or do the columns pre-exist? If they pre-exist, are there previous values that need to be retain?

Comment: The columns c:f exist and are filled with NA.  For each id, the NAs will be replaced with a 1 in the columns between 'start' and 'end' (inclusive)

Comment: Perhaps not very `data.table`-esque, but you may try matrix indexing: ``l = Map(`:`, match(d$a, names(d)), match(d$b, names(d)))``; `d[cbind(rep(seq_along(l), lengths(l)), unlist(l))] = 1L`. Seems a bit faster on large-ish data (`d[rep(1:.N, 1e6)]`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Answer to edited question

The OP has edited the question and [has disclosed more of the intentions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72120328/use-start-and-end-values-in-two-columns-to-specify-fill-range-over-remaining#comment127553086_72140597):

> imagine several million distinct IDs and a full range of possible
> start and end dates, spanning anywhere from a few days to a few years.
> The goal is to get a count of individuals that fall on each date

I have solved a similar problem with help of the `IRanges` package from Bioconductor:

```
install.packages("IRanges", repos = "https://bioconductor.org/packages/3.15/bioc")
library(IRanges)
cvr <- d[, coverage(IRanges(as.numeric(start.date), as.numeric(end.date)))]
data.table(start.date = lubridate::as_date(start(cvr)),
           end.date = lubridate::as_date(end(cvr)),
           count = runValue(cvr))
```

> ```
>    start.date   end.date count
> 1: 1970-01-02 2021-05-31     0
> 2: 2021-06-01 2021-07-01     1
> 3: 2021-07-02 2021-08-04     2
> 4: 2021-08-05 2021-09-12     1
> ```

The result represents the time scale where each row shows the number of overlaps  `count` (*coverage*) for each subperiod.

#### Explanation

The input dataset

> ```
>      id start.date   end.date
> 1: id_1 2021-06-01 2021-08-04
> 2: id_2 2021-07-02 2021-09-12
> ```

is converted to *integer ranges* in order to utilize the `coverage()` function from `IRanges`. `coverage()` returns a compact run-length encoded (RLE) representation of the subperiods:

```
cvr
```

> ```
> integer-Rle of length 18882 with 4 runs
>   Lengths: 18778    31    34    39
>   Values :     0     1     2     1
> ```

Finally, the RLE is converted to a data.frame with the integer ranges coerced back to `Date` class.

#### Usage

The result can be easily used in a variety of use cases:

```
result <- data.table(start.date = lubridate::as_date(start(cvr)),
           end.date = lubridate::as_date(end(cvr)),
           count = runValue(cvr))[-1]
```

Here, the date range has been trimmed, i.e., the first row was removed.

#### Plotting

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(result[]) +
  aes(x = start.date, y = count, xend = end.date, yend = count) +
  geom_segment()
```

[image]

#### Querying

```
result["2021-08-21" %between% .(start.date, end.date)]
```

> ```
>    start.date   end.date count
> 1: 2021-08-05 2021-09-12     1
> ```

#### Expanding (inverse RLE)

```
result[, .(Date = seq(start.date, end.date, by = 1), count), by = 1:nrow(result)]
```

> ```
>      nrow       Date count
>   1:    1 2021-06-01     1
>   2:    1 2021-06-02     1
>   3:    1 2021-06-03     1
>   4:    1 2021-06-04     1
>   5:    1 2021-06-05     1
>  ---                      
> 100:    3 2021-09-08     1
> 101:    3 2021-09-09     1
> 102:    3 2021-09-10     1
> 103:    3 2021-09-11     1
> 104:    3 2021-09-12     1
> ```

N.B.: With the development version 1.14.3 of data.table the code can be simplified by using `by = .I` for row-wise operations.

```
data.table::update.dev.pkg()
library(data.table)
result[, .(Date = seq(start.date, end.date, by = 1), count), by = .I]
```

## Answer to original question

As there are many rows and there is only a limited number of possibilities to fill in the `1`s in the matrix, my suggestion is to *join with a look-up table*.

```
lut <- fread(
"
a, b, c, d, e, f
c, d, 1, 1,NA,NA
c, e, 1, 1, 1,NA
c, f, 1, 1, 1, 1
d, e,NA, 1, 1,NA
d, f,NA, 1, 1, 1
e, f,NA,NA, 1, 1
")

lut[d, on =.(a, b), .(id, a, b, c, d, e, f)]
```

> ```
>    id a b  c d e  f
> 1: A1 c e  1 1 1 NA
> 2: B2 d f NA 1 1  1
> 3: C3 c e  1 1 1 NA
> 4: D4 d f NA 1 1  1
> ```

This approach is *faster by magnitudes* than [r2evans' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72120830/3817004) and consumes less memory. For a sample use case with 1 million rows, r2evans' approach took more than 30 seconds and allocated nearly 600 MBytes of memory while the join took less than 150 ms and allocated less than 100 MBytes of memory.

#### Benchmark details

```
library(bench)
col_names <- letters[3:6]
n_cols <- length(col_names)
lut_text <- 
"a, b, c, d, e, f
c, d, 1, 1,NA,NA
c, e, 1, 1, 1,NA
c, f, 1, 1, 1, 1
d, e,NA, 1, 1,NA
d, f,NA, 1, 1, 1
e, f,NA,NA, 1, 1"
bm <- press(
  n = 10^(1:6),
  {
    set.seed(42)
    ia <- sample(1:(n_cols - 1), n, replace = TRUE)
    ib <- pmin(ia + sample(1:(n_cols - 1), n, replace = TRUE), n_cols) 
    d <- data.table(id = 1:n,
                    a = col_names[ia],
                    b = col_names[ib]
    )
    for (col in col_names) {
      set(d, , col, NA_integer_)
    }
    str(d)
    mark(
      r2evans = {
        seq.character <- function(from, to, ...) {
          letters[seq(match(tolower(from), letters), 
                      match(tolower(to), letters), ...)]
        }
        newd <- rbindlist(Map(function(...) {
          o <- seq.character(...)
          setNames(as.list(rep(1L, length(o))), o)
        }, d$a, d$b), fill = TRUE, use.names = TRUE)
        cbind(d[,1:3], newd)
      },
      join = {
        lut <- fread(text = lut_text)
        lut[d, on =.(a, b), .(id, a, b, c, d, e, f)]
      }
    )
  }
)
bm
```

> ```
> # A tibble: 12 × 14
>    expression       n      min   median `itr/sec` mem_alloc `gc/sec` n_itr  n_gc total_time result       memory    
>    <bch:expr>   <dbl> <bch:tm> <bch:tm>     <dbl> <bch:byt>    <dbl> <int> <dbl>   <bch:tm> <list>       <list>    
>  1 r2evans         10  868.5µs  937.7µs 1002.        1.64MB    5.32    377     2    376.1ms <data.table> <Rprofmem>
>  2 join            10   2.43ms   2.99ms  322.      928.97KB    4.13    156     2   483.99ms <data.table> <Rprofmem>
>  3 r2evans        100   3.03ms   3.24ms  289.      109.08KB    8.45    137     4   473.24ms <data.table> <Rprofmem>
>  4 join           100   2.44ms   2.66ms  355.      140.84KB    2.03    175     1   493.48ms <data.table> <Rprofmem>
>  5 r2evans       1000  26.09ms  27.11ms   35.7     803.18KB   11.0      13     4   364.26ms <data.table> <Rprofmem>
>  6 join          1000   2.48ms   2.67ms  359.      225.21KB    4.12    174     2   485.02ms <data.table> <Rprofmem>
>  7 r2evans      10000 288.68ms 299.55ms    3.34      5.95MB    8.35      2     5    599.1ms <data.table> <Rprofmem>
>  8 join         10000   3.59ms    4.3ms  217.        1.04MB    3.98    109     2   502.33ms <data.table> <Rprofmem>
>  9 r2evans     100000    3.26s    3.26s    0.307    58.48MB    5.52      1    18      3.26s <data.table> <Rprofmem>
> 10 join        100000  12.14ms  13.07ms   64.7       9.28MB    7.84     33     4   509.99ms <data.table> <Rprofmem>
> 11 r2evans    1000000   30.76s   30.76s    0.0325   583.7MB    0.845     1    26     30.76s <data.table> <Rprofmem>
> 12 join       1000000  74.74ms 141.19ms    1.65     91.68MB    0.826     4     2      2.42s <data.table> <Rprofmem>
> # … with 2 more variables: time <list>, gc <list>
> ```

```
ggplot2::autoplot(bm)
```

[image]

Note that `bench::mark()` by default checks if the results are equal.

Comment: I am intrigued by the look up table, but I don't understand how to generate one programmatically.  I fear my toy example was misleading.  This is closer to what I'm dealing with:    
d<- data.table(id = c("id_1","id_2"), 
               start.date = c(as.Date("2021-06-01"), as.Date("2021-07-02")), 
               end.date = c(as.Date("2021-08-04"), as.Date("2021-09-12")))

but imagine several million distinct IDs and a full range of possible start and end dates, spanning anywhere from a few days to a few years.  The goal is to get a count of individuals that fall on each date.

Comment: I have updated the original question above to better reflect my request.  Sorry for the missteps, I am a true stack overflow rookie!

Comment: @matto, from the background information concerning problem size, I believe that `IRanges` from genomic research might be a suitable approach because of its compact run-length encoded representation of periods. Please, see my updated answer.

Comment: Thanks for this @Uwe, I didn't know about this package but it does exactly what I needed and it's incredibly fast.  Cheers,